# Go - exec.Command() but for string slice

Tags: function, go, exec, slice

Have someone idea is there any alternative for exec.Command() that is taking the parameters as []string not as single string ( ...string ) or idea how to pass the []string to exec.Command()?

Answer (score 4):

These are equivalent:

```
cmd := exec.Command("tr", "a-z", "A-Z")
```

And:

```
args := []string{"a-z", "A-Z"}
cmd := exec.Command("tr", args...)
```

To understand why, read [this section of the Go spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters).